# Knowingly posting a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I was interested in searching for a question asking about the link between food colouring and hyperactivity (and other harmful effects). A search didn't really return anything obvious, but way down the list (where most people wouldn't bother looking), I found a relevant question: [Do food additives ("E Number")  cause hyperactivity?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/502/is-any-of-the-e-number-additives-generally-accepted-as-harmful)

It would be great to have a duplicate question about the link between food colouring and hyperactivity that links to it. Is it ok to create one?

Comment: Can you submit an edit instead?

Comment: It wouldn't be the right thing to edit the question title as it's a perfect match for the answers given, but the existing title is not very good for being found easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the title and my answer (which is the accepted answer) to better reflect the actual question being asked. Truth be told, asking whether "X is harmful" is hardly informative. As I mentioned in my answer, at a concentration high enough, even vitamin C can be lethal.

The question is now specifically about hyperactivity, and the title reflects that. It should now be easier to find it through search, both here and on Google.

I have also deleted the answers which addressed the weaker claim ("Is X harmful?").

Comment: Surely answers should be downvoted rather than *deleted* ?

Answer (score 0):

Erm - why would you want to do that? The question already exists.

If you are wanting it to be easier to find, can you provide an answer that has new or useful information which has been missed so far?

If not, review the tags - are they appropriate for the search you carried out?

Is the question not as good as it should be - you can suggest edits.

Anyway - duplicates are a bad thing mmm'kay

Comment: The question that exists already has the desired answer, but the question title is too generic for people to be able to find it easily. It would be good to have a (closed) duplicate question with a suitable title that points to it. I seem to remember reading elsewhere in SE that duplicates are a good thing, as it provides extra pointers to the answers desired.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Probably but when it's intentional, it can be dangerous as it can create bad habits... :P